# Create rollover menu based on an image

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Maybe I'm just not meant for this stuff, but I cannot figure out how to put a rollover menu on my site. I want a centered dropdown menu where the text is hidden until you rollover an image. I already have the image, I just don't know what to do from here. I've taken CSS from other sites to try an backwards understand it but that really didn't help.

I'd prefer if it was CSS only because I'm even worse with JS

EDIT: Here's a JSFiddle: http://tinyurl.com/prwcm8g

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the HTML and CSS of your code or even better create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for it.. And please use better CSS for your website like : [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: The rollover menu as you refer it, as shown on the link you provided, is called an HTML Select tag. Read more about it: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp  As for text hiding when you hover over an image you need to look for `:hover` property in CSS.

Comment: Added the fiddle link.

Comment: @9Jay : do you want a dropdown to open when clicked on an Image ?? Based on what you had shown before the fiddle is completely different . But here is a fiddle with simple bootstrap CSS and the dropdown at the center :  http://jsfiddle.net/abhighosh18/7yzLrokm/1/

Comment: What I showed was where I am. Here, if you look at this fiddle, this is what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/3wjnpp0y/

Answer (score 1):

The code is pretty simple and if all you want is an rollover menu you would use pseudo classes such as a:hover and a:visited see:[pseudo classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

As to a previous commentors suggestion to use a pre-preprocessor kindly disregard. If you don't have a clear understanding of HTML/CSS learning a pre-processors script (SASS/LESS) will only hurt your education into how structural coding working with styling coding interacts with one another.

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.menu {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #000;
    width: 120px;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu li {
    padding: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.menu li a, .menu li a:visited {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3px 3px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    background: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: #ccc;
    border: #000 1px solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">links</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would really like to show you exactly how but you honestly would be best reading up on the material so you can troubleshoot your issue if need be and finetune the work. Plus that really isn't the best fiddle to showcase proper semantic IMO. The basics of the code is this though. 1) Make a unordered list<ul> 2) Populate list items 3) Add links/anchors<a> in each list item 4) Add sub <ul> for sub-menu items 5) Style with CSS See http://jsfiddle.net/3gmvyfee/